# Difference of "is" comparison in python's integer and list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I having a confusion in python `is` keyword

```
a=3
b=3
print(a is b)
```

This above code will print `True`.

**Meanwhile**,

```
a=[3,3]
b=[3,3]
print(a is b)
```

This code will print `False`.

And I know `is` compare object reference

**Can anyone can explain in detail or provide the link of documentation, how memory allocation and memory reference implemented in python ???? And explain how these two programs are different??**

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Python's semantics require that distinct instances of the *mutable* type `list` be created for `a` and `b`. Since `int` values are *immutable*, it's an implementation detail whether or not the same object is produced by the two uses of the literal `3`.